# GCC included header (using `-include`) changes not detected by CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm observing strange CMake behavior. If my project has a header file included to all sources using `-include inc.h` by means of `ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS(-include inc.h)` command then changes to the header never detected. Meaning I can change the header, but CMake will never try to recompile the `main.cpp`. Am I doing something wrong? Is it a CMake bug? Any workaround?

CMakeLists.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.12)
PROJECT(include_test)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(.)
ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS(
        -include inc.h
)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(include_test main.cpp)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    foo a;
    std::cout << a.bar << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

inc.h

```
struct foo
{
    int bar = 1;
    double baz = 3;
};
```

EDIT001:
As @Oliv suggests, when trying to use something like `SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(main.cpp PROPERTY OBJECT_DEPENDS inc.h)` Of course it wouldnt work because dependency should be a target and not a file on which the cpp depends so I added following:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(HeaderChanged
                  DEPENDS
                  inc.h
                  COMMENT "Checking if include file has changed")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(main.cpp PROPERTY OBJECT_DEPENDS HeaderChanged)
```

which still results in `make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'HeaderChanged', needed by 'CMakeFiles/include_test.dir/main.cpp.o'.  Stop.` despite the `HeaderChanged` target exists

Comment: Just don't use `-include`?

Comment: I think that in your specific example, inc.h is not recognized as a project source or header file since you do not explicitly include it in main.cpp. Thus, every time you touch inc.h you should clean and make again.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, it is existing state and I cant change it

Comment: @GergelyNyiri It is quite obvious why it is not working if CMake does not have any special treatment for such a case. The question is what can be done now.

Comment: If you can not change the compile option, maybe you can add `inc.h` to [OBJECT_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/prop_sf/OBJECT_DEPENDS.html) source file property for each file that includes it.

Comment: An other option would be to make a script that `touch` each source files to change their last modification time when `inc.h` is modified. It would be easy on linux, I don't know on other systems.

Comment: OBJECT_DEPENDS sounds like a good idea, will check it. Touching files, on the other hand is horrifically ugly.

Comment: @Olive, It didnt work, question updated

Comment: OBJECT_DEPENDS should work, it isn't quite clear what you mean by *dependency should be a target and not a file on which the cpp depends*.

Comment: @n.m. How the full command should be? something like `SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(main.cpp PROPERTY OBJECT_DEPENDS inc.h)`?

Comment: Yes exactly this.

Comment: @n.m. then I get *** No rule to make target 'inc.h'

Comment: This means make sees the right rule but cannot find the file. You should specify a valid path to inc.h.

Comment: @n.m. you are right! Odd thing, nor "inc.h" neither "./inc.h" worked. Dont get it why, everything is in the same directory. Is the current dir when the CMake is executing is `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` and not `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your EDIT0001: You probably need to specify the entire path to `inc.h` such that the Makefile knows where to find it (since you're most likely doing an out of source build), i.e:

`SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(main.cpp PROPERTIES OBJECT_DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/inc.h)`

Also note that the `OBJECT_DEPENDS` solution won't work for Visual Studio (neither does the flag `-include`). But in Visual Studio it was sufficient to add the `ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS(/FIinc.h)` and it would automatically detect changes to `inc.h`.

Comment: If I would use VS I wouldn't face above problems :) Out of office now, will check it tomorrow

Comment: Worked as expected. Thanks!