# How to make CMake's add_custom_command(TARGET ... POST_BUILD ...) depend on regular file?

Tags: cmake

Due to very special needs, I have a static library which I need to "post-process" after it is created. So I have this:

```
add_library(CANopenNode2 STATIC
        ...)
add_custom_command(TARGET CANopenNode2 POST_BUILD
        COMMAND objcopy --redefine-syms=renames.txt $<TARGET_FILE:CANopenNode2>)
```

My problem here is that the whole build step does not depend on `renames.txt` regular file - if I change it, the library does not get re-archived or re-processed. The `add_custom_command(TARGET ... POST_BUILD ...)` signature does not accept any `DEPENDS` argument. I've tried some regular tricks with creating a custom command (depending on that file), wrapped in custom target, which is then marked as a dependency for my static library `CANopenNode2`, but I most likely did something wrong, as it did not work at all. As I later need this "post-processed" library to be linked to my executable, I would prefer to work with `POST_BUILD` somehow, as I guess that using a regular custom command (which can depend on a file) would also be complicated, just in some other aspect, but I'm obviously open to suggestions.

Is there any way I could simply make the whole library depend on this regular file, or is this yet another thing that CMake makes extremely complicated?

Comment: @Tsyvarev - thanks for the info. I know about `LINK_DEPENDS`, but this affects linking of final binaries only. If I do that for my case, then when the regular file is changed, the library is not re-archived and re-processed - only the final executable is re-linked again...

Comment: Sorry, missed the point you build STATIC library which doesn't have link step, only the compile one. Does [OBJECT_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/prop_sf/OBJECT_DEPENDS.html) property works for you, as described in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52685787/gcc-included-header-using-include-changes-not-detected-by-cmake) and its answer? I could "swap" the duplicate references, but if you feel that your question needs a completely different answer, I would reopen it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - finally I settled for a `add_custom_command()` which generates an empty source (depending on my regular file), which then gets archived with the library. Adding `OBJECT_DEPENDS` is inconvenient in my case, as I actually compile the files twice, but I need to post-process only one copy of the library.

Comment: Ok, I have reopened the question. Feel free to write your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the best solution I came up with is this:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT CANopenNode2.c
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch CANopenNode2.c
        DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/renames.txt)
add_library(CANopenNode2 STATIC
        ...
        CANopenNode2.c)
add_custom_command(TARGET CANopenNode2 POST_BUILD
        COMMAND objcopy --redefine-syms=${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/renames.txt $<TARGET_FILE:CANopenNode2>)
```

This basically generates an empty source file (depending on my regular `renames.txt` file), which then gets archived in the static library along with other objects. Whenever `renames.txt` changes, this empty source is regenerated, the library is re-archived and reprocessed correctly.

Two other solutions that I've tried or considered:

1. `LINK_DEPENDS` property on the static library. Won't work, because static library does not have a link step. This is the best solution when you build an executable, but for a static library it's not useful.
2. `OBJECT_DEPENDS` property on one of the source files that are archived in the static library. This would work fine, however in my case it would be inconvenient, as I compile the sources twice, generate two static libraries, but only want to post-process one of them. With this approach when `renames.txt` file would change, CMake would rebuild both static libraries, while I need to rebuild only one of them.